# Eloquent ORM: how do I remove a specific item from a collection inside the each function?

Tags: eloquent

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-each), I have this similar code:

```
$collection = $collection->each(function ($item, $key) {
    if (/* some condition */) {
      //I want to remove this specific item:
      $item->delete(); //This is not working for me  
      //return false;
    }
});
```

So given a certain condition, I want to delete that specific Item.

I use the `->delete()` method but it doesn't work since I get the same `count()` results.

How do I remove those specific items?

I have tried `->pop()` but it does delete the items from the database! I just want to remove those items only in the collection. :-P

**Solution** As suggested by [Pawel Bieszczad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1335617/pawel-bieszczad), I tried with `->filter()` function (There're so many nice methods that my mind got blocked) so I got it working like this:

```
$filtered = $projects->filter(function($item)use($app,$lastyear,$thisyear){
  if(some_condition){
     return $item; //I do want to keep this item in the collection.
  }else{
     //Don't do anything. Remove item. I don't want to keep this item in the collection.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-filter) method